# Using py_compile.compile() from within a Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html).

My Python script generates Python code that runs much later, so I want to check now if what I generated is valid.

The docs say `py_compile.compile(file[, cfile[, dfile[, doraise]]])` and

> If doraise is true, a PyCompileError is raised when an error is encountered while compiling file

So, I tried

```
source = open(generatedScriptPath, 'rt').read() + '\n'

try:
    import py_compile
    x = py_compile.compile(source, '', '', True)

except py_compile.PyCompileError, e:
    print str(e)
```

but the inner Exception is never hit, instead an outer Exception is being caught:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"H:/code/testgen/testGen.py", line 293, in <module>  
    x = py_compile.compile(source, '', '', True)   File   "C:\Python27\lib\py_compile.py", line 106, in compile  
    with open(file, 'U') as f: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or   directory: '# This script was auto-generated  ...
```

How can I fix this? Note that I am open to alternatives, I just want to ask the simplest way. "Is the code I just generated syntactically valid Python?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message: "No such file or directory".  The first argument is supposed to be a file name to open.  Or read the docs: "The source code is loaded from the file name /file/."  You might prefer the "compile" builtin, which can compile a string of Python.

Comment: Thanks. I had just copied some other code from S.O. I was surprised that it did that. Anyway, it compiles now, but doesn't throw an exception on invalid code. Would you prefer me to update this question, or start a new one?